# Поддержка паттерна регистра штормом

Tags: phpstorm, php

Привет Всем!
Дело в том, что регистр объектов возвращает всегда разный объект, например, `$registry->getModel('ModelName')`.

Шторм не будет понимать, что это экземпляр класса `ModelName_Model`. Можно его этому как-то научить? Может, скриптик какой-то прописать куда-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@iproger](/users/1720/iproger)](/users/1720/iproger), только для [статичных методов](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata). Для добавления подобного функционала для обычных методов голосовать [здесь](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18075). Пока приходится делать так:

```
/** @type Filesystem $filesystem */
$filesystem = $container->get('filesystem');
```

> ModelName_Model

Господи неееееееееет, не надо пихать такие суффиксы, не надо никаких подчеркиваний. В идеале и всяких Serializer в JsonSerializer быть не должно, все это должно быть указано в неймспейсе.

> [(-) Encodings in Names – No prefixes, no type/scope information](http://www.planetgeek.ch/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Clean-Code-V2.2.pdf)

Comment: Проект старый, классов уже очень много на пространства имён переходить очень неудобно теперь, спасибо! ПО PSR именно подчёркивания, старо, но верно.

Comment: >>не надо пихать такие суффиксы, не надо никаких подчеркиваний

сейчас половина фреймворков так работает =/

Comment: @mountpoint, потому что фреймворков, которыми можно пользоваться, от силы полтора.